# How to configure Amazon AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity for access token in Ionic 3 project?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, ionic3, amazon-cognito

I'm little bit confuse using AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity method.
let me describe step by step.

Step 1:-I get the facebook token from facebook.

Step 2:-using getId method, I get the IdentityId from amzon cognito.

Step 3:-used getOpenIdToken and passed the IdentityId I get the {IdentityId,Token} in response.

(Question 1: Can I access the amazon services using this token?)

Step 4:- Then I'm trying to implement AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity method

using the params:-

```
params = {
        RoleArn: arn:aws:iam::XXXXX:role/XXXXX,
        RoleSessionName: 'XXXX',
        WebIdentityToken: 'XXXX'
        DurationSeconds: 3600,
        ProviderId: 'www.amazon.com'
    };

    let sts = new AWS.STS();
    sts.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else console.log(data);
})
```

Question 2:-WebIdentityToken ,I have to use which one the provided by the facebook or by the cognito in return of getOpenIdToken method.

Question 3:- ProviderId, I am trying to logged in using facebook is it will be graph.facebook.com or www.amazon.com?

Question 4: When I am using **WebIdentityToken** as provide by **getOpenIdToken** in response and **ProviderId** as **www.amazon.com** I'm getting **InvalidIdentityToken**: Provided Token is not a Login With Amazon token

Question 5:- When I am using **WebIdentityToken** as provide by **facebook** and **ProviderId** as **graph.facebook.com** I'm getting AccessDenied: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity

If it's right how to give access please tell step by step

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, if you have any solution about my problem please help

Comment: Login with Amazon is a different Identity Provider similar to Facebook, Google, etc. Therefore you want to use graph.facebook.com.

Answer (score 1):

Your end goal seems to be to obtain temporary AWS credentials for your app users. You do not need to interact with AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity for this. Amazon Cognito Federated Identities directly vends AWS credentials and hides all the STS interactions.

As explained in [authentication flow documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html), you need to interact with GetId and GetCredentialsForIdentity APIs and your app user will directly get temporary AWS credentials.

As for answer to your Question 3, no the OpenId token vended by GetOpenIdToken cannot be used with AWS APIs directly. For detailed explanation, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180065/aws-cognito-token-types/31191303#31191303).